# how can i stop auto popup of keyboard, in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

in my application i wish to stop that auto popup of Keyboard while focus on edittext.. can any one assist me.. thanks in advance..

main.xml

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions.

Try hiding it when focus changes or when user clicks it:

```
uredittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  onClick(View v)
  {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.uredittext).getWindowToken(), 0);
   });
```

or

```
uredittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
  onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
  {
    if(hasFocus)
     {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.uredittext).getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
    }
);
```